# Store a variable for each frontend user in a Web API C# controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I have a React frontend and WebAPI C# backend. I have a controller with a Get method, the user will make repeated calls to it.

```
namespace myProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class myController: ControllerBase
{ int currentIndex = 0;
[HttpGet(Name = "GetStreamLetter")] public Letter Get() {

         currentIndex++;
            // prepare the object to return - select the object at position 
            // currentIndex from a list defined in the backend
        return objectToReturn;
    }
}
}
```

What I want is for each user to have a currentIndex value at a given moment in time. The object to return depends on this currentIndex, and I want it to increase it every time a user makes the get call. Note that the value stored must be different for each user.

If I leave the code as shown above, it will reset the counter on each get call (I assume since it's stateless). If I make the counter static, it will work but when the user refreshes the page it doesn't reset and will continue to increase forever. I'm also not sure if static would create a separate variable for each user, which is a requirement.

Comment: Use internal memory cache or external like Redis. to save your information on it.

Comment: You can use cache to achieve it. Or add one column(currentId int) in your user table, every time the user access this endpoint, currentId++.

Comment: I'd actually _discourage_ this. This will give the API state ([and you'd usually not want that](https://restfulapi.net/idempotent-rest-apis/)). Why can't the client count for itself and `GET` with a certain index? Then it can reset, jump, increment as it needs to and none of that needs to go into your backend logic.

Comment: Workaround would be to pass data in query params and in repsonse, something like `?index=10`m then in backend: `response.LastIndex = indexFromQuery + 1; response.Item = GetItem(indexFromQuery + 1)`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn If at all, I'd include a `NextIndex` if those happened to be not perfectly sequential.

Comment: Thank you all for your ideas. I agree to Fildor's point - this isn't something I should do, the client should ask for next element in the sequence. I was worried that someone might intercept that request and modify it, therefore finding out about the elements in the sequence too early; but this won't really protect it either - they can just make n calls to get to the nth element. I will find some other way to protect against that outcome on the frontent.